# How to use malloc when calling strcat()?

Tags: c, malloc, strcat

I'm coding a small program to copy text information from a file, edit and save it to another one. When I try to execute the instruction

```
a=fputs( strcat( "\"", strcat(string, "\",\n")), novo_arquivo);
```

it gives me the segmentation fault core dumped error. Researching, I found out that I must use malloc to allocate memory, but I don't know how this code should be written.

Comment: The first argument of `strcat()` is the destination, but you've given it a read-only character array of size 1. What is the intended behavior?

Comment: I can't believe I've done this KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK thanks for the comment, helped a lot

Comment: You don't *need* to use `malloc()`: you can allocate a char array of enough size, if you know 'enough' in advance.

Comment: You're better off using `fprintf()` here... `fprintf(novo_arquivo, "\"%s\"\n", string);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rough example of using `strcat()` with dynamic memory might look something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>  // for printf
#include <string.h> // for strcat
#include <stdlib.h> // for calloc

int main()
{
    char* novo_arquivo = "example_string";
    // size + 3 to account for two quotes and a null terminator
    char* concat_string = calloc(strlen(novo_arquivo) + 3, sizeof(*concat_string));
    strcat(concat_string, "\"");
    strcat(concat_string, novo_arquivo);
    strcat(concat_string, "\"");
    // write concat_string to a file...
    printf("%s", concat_string);
    free(concat_string);
}
```

You're declaring `concat_string` on the heap instead of the stack, so you'll need to free it when you're finished using it, or you'll create a memory leak.